# React Native - how to optimize app performance with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, optimization, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using React Native (version 0.46) to develop an app which does a few fetches data from a few resources, renders it and stores the data for display when internet connection is unavailable.

**My question**: I'm trying to see if its better to apply the "new" plan mentioned below instead of the current. Since RN is using [JavaScript Core](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-runtime), is it running the code in a non blocking way like Node.js? advice is appreciated.

**Current:**
1. The app loads.
2. Check for internet connection (Asynchronously ofcourse).
3. If there is a connection: First, render cached data(if it exists), and second fetch for new data. If there is internet connection but no cached data, just fetch new data.
4. If there is no internet connection, fetch new data, render and store it.

**New**: Rather than waiting for internet availability, im simply going to render the cached data if available. Would this be a better approach? or is there a better one ?

Comment: If you have a lot of data i would go for prioritize the render of cached data first. But that's depend a lot of the context of your app. If your user need last data or can he wait for have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. add redux-persist to the app**.

**2. whitelist all the state keys that need to be
    persisted.**

**3. make the api calls** if there is a network connection
    and refresh the state if they are successful

Note:  I had to delay render (in v4 of redux-persist) until the storage is rehydrated this might not be needed in newer versions.

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Another solution could be the redux-offline module:

https://github.com/jevakallio/redux-offline